# Running Applet with specific JRE version

Tags: java, applet

I have embedded my applet in an HTML and added `<param name="java_version" value="1.6*">` to force my applet to run with 1.6* java version.

```
<APPLET width="500" height="500">
 <PARAM name="code" value="org.me.hello.MyApplet">
 <PARAM name="archive" value="../jar/Hello.jar">
 <param name="java_version" value="1.6*">
</APPLET>
```

Java 1.6 was not installed in my system so when the html page tried to launch the applet with JAVA 1.6 it said `JAVA 1.6 is not installed in your system.Do you want to run with latest version?`.I allowed it to run with latest version and it worked(ran with 1.7 which was installed)
[image]

**Now the problem came when i launched this applet second time.It did not ask me whether to run with latest vesion or not.It directly ran with JAVA 1.7. I then installed JAVA 1.6 also but still same problem.** How do i solve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Go to this location :
`C:\Users\[username]\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment`

Delete everything